# Substract 5 min from current date

Tags: bash

I tried to subtract 5 min to my date but it adds to it 5 hours and 1 min.

I need to subtract 5 minutes to a date in Linux the result that I expect is 08:56:56, but it doesn't work.

```
NOW=$( date '+%H:%M:%S' )
09:01:56
NEW_TIME=$(date -u -d "$NOW - 5 minutes" "+%H:%M:%S")
14:02:56
```

Comment: Try "5 minutes ago"?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
NOW=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
NOW2=$(date '+%s')                                  # current time in seconds since epoch
NEW_TIME=$(date -d "@$((NOW2 - 300))" '+%H:%M:%S')  # subtract 300 seconds (5 minutes)
```

Output:

```
10:52:27      # echo $NOW
1701165147    # echo $NOW2
10:47:27      # echo $NEW_TIME
```

**EDIT:**

This way is better:

```
NOW=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
NEW_TIME=$(date -d "-5 min" "+%H:%M:%S")
```

Output:

```
12:48:48   # echo $NOW
12:43:48   # echo $NEW_TIME
```

Comment: This needlessly copies the OP's attempt with two indications of `date`. The system already knows the current date; all you need is `date -d "-5 min"`

Comment: @tripleee updated in the edit part, thanks.